# NSMutableArray to array from json

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I need to convert an NSMutableArray to an NSArray from JSON. I loaded the JSON and put it in an NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *banner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
banner = [responseObject objectForKey:@"banner"];
```

This is test for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [slider count]; i++) {
      NSLog(@"%@", [[banner objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"resim"]);      }
```

This is log from the JSON:

```
(
        {
        id = 1;
        resim = "http://localhost/sample_Files/banner_api/1.jpg";
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        resim = "http://localhost/sample_Files/banner_api/2.jpg";
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        resim = "http://localhost/sample_Files/banner_api/3.jpg";
    }
)
```

I want to set all of this to be like the below NSArray:

```
NSArray *allImages = @[@"http://localhost/sample_Files/banner_api/1.jpg",@"http://localhost/sample_Files/banner_api/2.jpg",@"http://localhost/sample_Files/banner_api/3.jpg"];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * muArr = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSDictionary * dict in yourMuArr) {
  [muArr addObject:dict[@"resim"]];
}
NSArray * allImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:muArr];
```